# Field not found on "Document data policies" Form in Ax 2012 (AIF)

Tags: xml, schema, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, aif

I'm configuring the document data policies for a given entity (TrvPBSMaindata), but there's one field missing (CostType) and I can't find the reason.

All the other fields seems to be there, and I've compared it with the behavior of some other fields and can't find a reason why it is not there.

I've already checked it's AxBC - both the "parm" and "set" methods are there and properly coded.

Also, the service have been updated some times on the last two day.

What are the requirements that a table field must fulfill for it to be included on the AIF's Inbound Port's XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Table field has to be visible
- Parm Method on class AxTableName has to exist
- The query that is used for the service has to use that
  field
- Service has to be refreshed using form AIFServices or by
  deploying a service group containing the service